# Problem accessing Spark UI with Pyspark on YARN over WSL(v1)

Tags: networking, pyspark, port, hadoop-yarn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Ubuntu 18.014 WSL system set-up for testing out spark features.

pyspark - 3.0.1 (PyPi)
Hadoop - 3.2.1
Hive - 3.1.2

I can run spark locally, and open the Spark UI (localhost:4040) just fine.

```
pyspark --master local[*]
```

But if I use YARN client mode,

```
pyspark --master YARN --num-executors
```

and try to access Spark UI - Following errors are seen:

```
1. When typing localhost:4040
Result - It opens "http://"WindowsHostname".localdomain:8088/proxy/application_1601537044940_0003/"
```

WHICH gives an error.

```
"WindowsHostname".localdomain’s server IP address could not be found.

2. If I manually change the URL part from http://"WindowsHostname".localdomain to localhost:

localhost:8088/proxy/application_1601537044940_0003/
```

I get to the error page:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /proxy/application_1601537044940_0003/. Reason:

Server Error
Caused by:
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607).....so on
```

This seems like WSL does not get network access to YARN "proxy" port.

Ques. Is there any way I can give WSL the necessary accces to port defined by YARN?

Ques. Can I give access to http://"WindowsHostname".localdomain in WSL? or map http://"WindowsHostname".localdomain to localhost.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.